# C# Replace All Vowels in Generic List

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How do I replace all vowels in list with a space? Following code does not seem to be working.

```
        List<string> Instruments = new List<string>();

        Instruments.Add("cello");
        Instruments.Add("guitar");
        Instruments.Add("violin");
        Instruments.Add("double bass");

        string vowels = "a e i o u y";


        Instruments.ForEach(w=>vowels = vowels.Replace(w,""));
```

**Expected Result:**

```
cll
gtr
vln
```

Comment: From : Replace(w,"")); To : Replace(w," "));

Comment: does not seem to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var vowels = new List<char> {'a','e','i','o','u','y'};

var result = new List<string>();
Instruments.ForEach(w => result.Add(new string(w.Select(x => vowels.Any(y => y == x) ? ' ' : x).ToArray())));
```

Comment: Could `vowels` be `HashSet` instead?

Comment: @HardyWest Just by practice. I recommend learning about collections and LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You should use .Select if need to changes values in Collection:

```
List<string> Instruments = new List<string>();

        Instruments.Add("cello");
        Instruments.Add("guitar");
        Instruments.Add("violin");
        Instruments.Add("double bass");

        var regex = new Regex("^a|e|i|o|u", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        var withoutVowels = from instr in Instruments
            select regex.Replace(instr, string.Empty);

        foreach (var item in withoutVowels)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little quick and dirty but this works for me.

```
  List<string> Instruments = new List<string>();
  var newList = new List<String>();

  Instruments.Add("cello");
  Instruments.Add("guitar");
  Instruments.Add("violin");
  Instruments.Add("double bass");

  List<string> vowels = new List<string> { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y" };

  Instruments.ForEach(w =>
  {
    var temp = w;
    vowels.ForEach(v =>
    {
      temp = temp.Replace(v, "");
    });
    newList.Add(temp);
  });

  newList.ForEach(w => Console.WriteLine(w));
```

Comment: Consider setting `Capacity` of `newList` to the `Length` of `Instruments`.

Answer (score 0):

`Instruments` has a collection of `string`, or words, in it.  Your `.ForEach` iterates through that collection where each instance is `w`, but you're not affecting those instances with your usage of `.Replace` here, you're using them in an operation to affect the string `vowels`.

see [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) MSN Documentation.

As such, you need to also iterate through your `vowels` `string`, and use the `char`instance of `vowels`: `w.Replace(v, " ")`, where `w` is your word instance in `Instruments`, and `v` is your vowel instance in `vowels`:

So, it should be `Instruments.ForEach(w => foreach (vowelChar in vowels.split(" ")) { w.Replace(vowelChar, " "); });`

Note: @mjwills pointed out the other issue with this operation in comments. the assignment to `w` won't persist here. so, you'll need to create new `List<string>` in some fashion to persist it (either declare it before hand and add to it in iteration, or use Linq `.ToList<T>` Extension of `IEnumerable<T>`.

---

However, that is inefficient since you're essentially creating a `char[]` from `vowels` `string` using `.Split` on each iteration of `Instruments`.

Instead, you should defined your `vowels` as a `char[]` to avoid the necessity of that operation: `var vowels = new char[] {'a','e','i','o','u', 'y'};`

```
    List<string> Instruments = new List<string>();

    Instruments.Add("cello");
    Instruments.Add("guitar");
    Instruments.Add("violin");
    Instruments.Add("double bass");

    char[] vowels = new char[] {'a','e','i','o','u','y'};

    Instruments.ForEach(w => {
        foreach (char v in vowels) {
           w = w.Replace(v, ' ');
        }
    });
```

---

EDIT: assigning to `w` instances of `Instruments` in the iteration don't persist, so you would need to create a new instance of `List<string>` for your results.

```
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    Instruments.ForEach(w => {
        foreach (char v in vowels) {
           results.Add(w.Replace(v, ' '));
        }
    });

    results.ForEach(w => Console.WriteLine(w));
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You could try the same with with Regex:

```
public void ReplaceAllVowels()
{
    List<string> Instruments = new List<string>();

    Instruments.Add("cello");
    Instruments.Add("guitar");
    Instruments.Add("violin");
    Instruments.Add("double bass");

    var pattern = new Regex("[aeiouy]");
    var lst = Instruments.Select(i => pattern.Replace(i, "")).ToList();
    foreach (var item in lst)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works nicely for me:

```
List<string> Instruments = new List<string>();

Instruments.Add("cello");
Instruments.Add("guitar");
Instruments.Add("violin");
Instruments.Add("double bass");

string vowels = "aeiouy";

var results = vowels.Aggregate(Instruments,
    (i, v) => i.Select(x => x.Replace(v.ToString(), "")).ToList());
```

I get:

```
cll 
gtr 
vln 
dbl bss
```